# Qt Widgets FullScreen Margin

Tags: c++, qt, fullscreen, qwidget, qwebview

I want to create a program that loads google in literally full screen, so I achieved opening my qt program in full screen using `w.showFullScreen();` and it works perfectly, however when I add the `QWebView` and set it to `centralWidget` like this:

[image]

but when I run the program, I get some margins on the sides of the window, in other words the `QWebView` isn't literally in fullScreen harmoniously with the window which is, it looks like this:

[image]

I don't think my code is mistaken but here it is
untitled.pro:

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2015-02-07T21:25:42
#
#-------------------------------------------------

CONFIG   += release

QT       += core gui
QT       += webkitwidgets
```

main.cpp

```
w.showFullScreen();
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QtWebKitWidgets>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->webView->load(QUrl("http://www.google.com"));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your central widget have a layout. It's possible that you have layoutLeftMargin, layoutRightMargin, layoutTopMargin, layoutBottomMargin with others values than 0 got in you QtDesigner click on your central widget and at the down of you properties set the margins to 0.